# query with date greater not working in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb-compass

Object looks like this:

```
_id:748633163339

lastModifiedDate:2019-06-02 00:57:34.077
```

My query looks like this:

`{"lastModifiedDate": {$gt: ISODate("2022-03-10")} }`

I'm looking for all entries after 3/10 2022. I am unable to execute the query in compass. What is wrong with it?